# How to make something visible after hiding it with SetActive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

I am creating a mobile game and I want to add dialogue. I've been able to get the dialogue box to "pop up" and update it.

I was able to hide my health bar when clicking the starting button for the dialogue (I have done this by using the `SetActive` function), but now I have no idea how to show the health bar again on the last click on the `continue` button. The continue button also makes the dialogue box disappear.

Also, tell me if you need to see any project code.

Comment: If you want to show the button again have you tried using SetActive or Enable?

Comment: Please post the code that deactivates the hp bar and shows the dialogue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a pointer to where you are in your dialogue list. When you reach last element turn it on.

```
int dialoguePointer = 0;
string[] dialogueList;

void OnContinueClick() {
if (dialoguePointer == dialogueList.size - 1) {
healthbar.SetActive(true);
} else {
LoadNextDialogue();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two questions, one on your title, and another one in your question-description.

For the title one "**How to count button clicks in Unity**":

If you are using mouse clicks:

```
public int touchCount = 0;
void Update ()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        touchCount++;
    }
}
```

If you are using tap inputs (cause you're talking about a mobile game):

```
public int touchCount = 0;
void Update ()
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        touchCount++;
    }
}
```

And for the description one which seems "**How to disable an element**":

Use what @amitklein suggest, `gameObject.SetActive(false)`, to disable the object you don't want to see.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are using `GameObject.Find("Hp Bar")` and it fails when the hp bar is inactive. You can keep a reference to the hp bar to avoid this:

```
GameObject hpBar = GameObject.Find("Hp Bar");
hpBar.setActive(false);
... code of dialogue
//once dialogue is done, set hpBar active again
hpBar.setActive(true);
```